# Riemann-Roch theorem without heavy tools

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have read two proofs of Riemann-Roch : one very quick in Forster, *Lecture on Riemann Surfaces* which use cohomology of sheaf, and results from functional analysis.

Another one is in the book of Miranda about Riemann surfaces, which is more elementary, but use lot of intermediate results and especially snake lemma.

Each time I'm reading one of these proofs, I just can't convince myself that is true because I have to believe these results in functionnal analysis, or the snake lemma. To me it looks really like powerful and a bit mysterious results (even it's probably a basic result for most of mathematician). So my question is

> Can we find a reasonably short proof of Riemann-Roch which not use homological algebra or functional analysis and which is "almost" elementary ?

I'm aware that this theorem is quite powerful so we probably need a bit of work or powerful theorem. But, what is the most "effective" proof which use not too much big results ?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but the snake lemma shouldn't be so mysterious - it's possible to give a quite concrete proof.

Comment: If you have one, I'm interested by this proof.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etbcKWEKnvg

Comment: The are lots of details to check, of course, but the thing that looks mysterious about the snake is where the connecting map from the last cokernel to the first kernel comes from. [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/182567/7062) a good attempt to motivate the existence of this map.

Comment: There is another proof of RR for curves due to Weil (and presented tersely in Serre's Algebraic Groups and Class fields). It is conceptually simpler but does use Adeles which might need some getting used to (if you have never seen them before). The benefit of this approach is that it gives a uniform proof for smooth curve over any field without mentioning sheaves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**WARNING:** Miranda does not prove the Riemann-Roch for a Riemann surface $X$ but only for a smooth  projective curve $C$.
 It is impossible to prove Riemann-Roch for $X$ in the holomorphic case without some highly non-trivial analysis, which essentially proves that there are exist non constant meromorphic functions on $X$.
This is acknowledged by Miranda at the beginning of chapter VI of his (excellent) book.

**Answer to your question**
The snake lemma is small beer but there is no easy way of proving  Riemann-Roch for a compact Riemann surface not known *a priori* to be algebraic: any proof involves difficult (functional) analysis.
Riemann's  remarkable result  is that   the Riemann surface $X$ actually **is** an algebraic curve $C$, but to prove this is  the core difficulty.